# Display a random number, ask the user to input the same number, and continue if the numbers match

Tags: batch-file

I want to show a random number to the user. Then, I want the user to be able to type in the same number. If the two numbers match, the program should continue. If the numbers do not match, a new random number should be generated and the process should start over.

Here is what I have so far:

```
color 0

cls

echo.

echo type the Number u See %random%

echo.

set Nh=

set /p Nh=Number Here:

if %Nh%==%random% Goto lol
```

Comment: Why do you `set` *Nh* twice? `set /p Nh` is enough.

Comment: ok thx for that tips

Comment: Setting `Nh` makes sense to reset its value, because pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> at `set /P` returns previous value of `Nh`.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with your existing code is that every time the `%random%` variable is used, it becomes a different random number, so the random number that is displayed in your code is not the random number that is used for checking the user's input. This means that there is only a 1/32768 chance that they will be able to progress correctly.

You should set the initial random number to a different variable so that the value will not change.

```
:show_number
color 0
cls

echo.
set rand_num=%random%
echo The number you see: %rand_num%
echo.

set /p "nh=Number here: "
if "%nh%" equ "%rand_num%" goto lol
goto show_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `else` statement, and create a checkpoint called `:random`.

```
:random
color 0
cls
echo.
echo type the Number u See %random%
echo.
set /p Nh=Number Here:
if %Nh%==%random% (
    Goto lol
) else (
    Goto random
)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the intended behaviour, but as it is coded, it is really hard to type the correct number